# Active Storage New Primary Key in Model Not working for attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I've recently updated a model to use a new primary key. All the associations are working fine except the attachments (has_one_attached) through Active Storage.

The attachments were working fine before, but since I changed the primary key of said model, the active_storage_attachments table stores the record_id as 0.

My quess is it may be because the record_id in active_storage_attachments is an interger and my new primary key is a string? Is there an easy fix?

My model:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
    self.primary_key = 'encrypted_id'
    encrypts :surname, :names

    validates_presence_of :names
    belongs_to :family
    has_many :kids, primary_key: :encrypted_id, foreign_key: :person_encrypted_id
    has_one_attached :photo

end
```

Comment: ActiveStorage saves all your attachments in one single table and points to the resource that "owns" the attachment using a polymorphic assocation. While you could "fix" this by changing the type of `active_storage_attachments.resource_id` you're breaking the functionality for every other model in the system. Why is it you think you actually need a different primary key? This smells like security by obscurity.

Comment: If you really need this you can add an intermediary model (Photo) with normal PK which `has_one_attached :photo_attachement` without breaking the default functionality. Its kind of wonky but ActiveStorage is a very opinionated design that's really just designed be have a minimum of required configuration at the cost of flexibility.

Comment: Just wanted to know if there is a way. Thanks, the intermediary was my second option also